# ActionMailer with SMTP - Bad recipient address syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

My user has email with this format: "-user-@domain.com". Mailgun validation succeeded but Rails couldn't send email to the address. I'm using SMTP with Mandrill.
This is the error message:

```
/home/johnny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:948:in `check_response': 401 4.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax (Net::SMTPServerBusy)
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated:**

This sample code (with valid SMTP configuration) would raise the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'mail'

options = {
    address:      "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    port:     587,
    domain:     "mydomain.com",
    authentication:   "login",
    user_name:    "myemail@mydomain.com",
    password:     "mypassword",
    enable_starttls_auto: false
}

Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, options
end

Mail.deliver do
    from 'valid.email@domain.com'
    to "-test-@domain.com"
    subject 'Testing sendmail'
    body 'Testing sendmail'
end
```

Comment: What about showing some example code? Eg. the mail-sending code and/or the smtp configuration?

Comment: Code and configuration is working fine, the error only raises with that email.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the starting dash in the email address is valid, most mail servers do not accept such emails due to restrictions for command line arguments.

A quick fix you can try is wrapping the email address with angle brackets:

```
Mail.deliver do
  from 'valid.email@domain.com'
  to "<-test-@domain.com>"
  subject 'Testing sendmail'
  body 'Testing sendmail'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's still not working with the same error.

Comment: I fear this is not an easy task to solve, and probably you won't. Maybe using an email alias for that one can fix the issue, but your user should provide you one.

Comment: Thank you @marzapower for your helps. I will check if there is another way to solve it, otherwise I have to abandon such kind of address.

Comment: I have some other important things to resolve, so I'll be back in several days...